# how to update mirrored remote repository(own server) when someone has pushed to the main remote repostiory(gitlab)?

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks

I have the main remote Gitlab repository(A) and clone mirrored to another remote server(B), I would like to know how to update the (B)remote server when someone pushed to the main Gitlab repository(A).

Comment: You can have a daemon on your own server B that does a regular `git ls-remote A` and does a pull if the response is different from the previous result. (For this high-level response, I'll just say "and be careful of race conditions".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [a **pull mirroring**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/repository_mirroring.html), as [described here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/repository_mirroring.html#pulling-from-a-remote-repository-starter):

> Repository mirroring allows for mirroring of repositories to and from external sources. It can be used to mirror branches, tags, and commits between repositories.

It [was introduced](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/3283#note_51985284) in GitLab 10.3 for January 2018.